# Non java services with jHipster

Tags: jhipster, netflix-zuul

Can JHipster gateway work with non-java, non JHipster microservices? Say, by importing swagger.json of the target microsevrice and by making those microservice instances register with jH registry and UAA?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should work as long as the microservice exposes its swagger spec at `/v2/api-docs`. The service should register with the JHipster registry probably using Spring Cloud Netflix Sidecar as explained by David Steiman in [this article](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/01/18/spring-cloud-sidecar-applications/) and David is also the man behind UAA for JHipster.